# problem with progress dialog in android

Tags: android, progressdialog

in my app when i click a button i am getting some data from network and i am opening a new activity. At that time i am trying to show a progress bar in my screen. Following is my code

```
 dialog = new ProgressDialog(SearchPage.this);
  dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
  dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
  dialog.show();
  new Thread() {
     public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(300);  
        }
    catch (InterruptedException e) 
           {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }              
        getWebPageContents(url);
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SearchList.class);
       startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);  
                }
              }.start();
```

The app is working fine and the progress dialog is also working. Now the problem is when i press the back button from second activity the first activity gets opened and the progress dialog gets started and running continuously without stopping.

It gets stopped if i press the back button. I dont want the progress dialog to be viewed when i returning  back to the first activity. How to do this........

Comment: So in your first Activity you start a ProgressDialog, then you start an Activity where the Dialog is not visible, and when you return to your first Activity you want the ProgressDialog to dissapear?

Comment: The best way is to use `AsyncTask` [Tutorial](http://www.xoriant.com/blog/mobile-application-development/android-async-task.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `dialog.dismiss()` before starting the new activity. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code after

```
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
dialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can dismiss the dialog directly after your call to the Activity by calling

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

after

```
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

If you want to dismiss the dialog only when you've returned from this Activity, you need to make sure `dialog` is a field, and call `dialog.dismiss();` in `onActivityResult`(You may want to check for `dialog != null` first).

Answer (score 0):

Add following code after

```
dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
dialog.setCancelable(false);
```